# Get my collection, req.query (express,node.js)

Tags: r, node.js, mongodb, express, action

I want to recover my collection which is in the database.
The problem is that my query is still not defined.

Here is my request:

```
const products = {
  getProducts: async (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.query.id;
    console.log(productId);
    const product = await ProductsModel.find({}).exec();

    if (product instanceof Error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Error" });
      return;
    }

    res.json(product);
  },
};
module.exports = products;
```

My schema with mongoose :

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Products = mongoose.model("Products", ProductSchema);

module.exports = Products;
```

My Fetch :

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
useEffect(getProducts, []);

async function getProducts() {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
    }

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/products", options);
    const productsData = await response.json();

    setProducts(productsData);
    console.log(productsData);
  }
```

My error message :

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`

(node:4279) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.

(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

**undefined**

GET /products 304 14.493 ms - -

**Thank you in advance for your help.**

Comment: Why do you await this: `const productsData = await response.json();`

Comment: What do you mean with error: The deprecation warning or that log is writing `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

At first, while exporting from your Schema file you have done:

```
module.exports = Products;
```

But on your **Request file** while fetching product you have done:

```
const product = await ProductsModel.find({}).exec();
```

You should replaced it with:

```
const product = await Products.find({}).exec();
```

You are getting **undefined on req.query** because while request on server you have not passed query. To pass query use **?id=**
In your **Fetch File** you should do following change:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/products?id="+productId, options);
```

Or, You can also use **Tempelate Literals ``**, this is a good practice.

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/products?id=${productId}`, options);
```

For deprecation warning, you have to do following changes where you have connect databse.

```
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/name',{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex:true},()=>{console.log('database connected')}
```